# Deleting google maps heatmap layer

Tags: google-maps, heatmap

I am writing a google heatMap application and I need to delete the data which heatmap layer contains. Is there some solution? I went trough all stack overflow and can not find the proper solution. Everywhere they advise to do something like this:

`heatmap.setMap(null)` but this only hides the map, and when I do `heatmap.setMap(map)` the layer appears again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete a variable in javascript  but you can assign  as  undefined

```
 heatmap = undefined;
```

so heatmap  is not a valid  object

Comment: Doing what you suggested has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily just set the data to an empty array

```js
heatmap.setData([])
heatmap.setMap(this.map)
```